# Help with tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, line

Hello I need to write a multiple state model in latex, my code is as follows

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        % Draw the states
        \node[state]             (aa) {Husband Alive- Wife Alive (0)};
        \node[state, right=of aa] (ad) {Husband Alive- Wife Dead(1)};
 \node[state, below=of ad] (dd){Husband Dead- Wife Dead(3)};
  \node[state, below=of aa] (da){Husband Dead- Wife Alive(4)};
        % Connect the states with arrows
        \draw[every loop,
              ]
            (aa) edge[right ] node {$m_{x+t:y+t}^{01}$} (ad)
            (ad) edge[ right] node {} (dd)
            (da) edge[right] node {} (dd)
            (aa) edge[ right] node {} (da);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can i make the length of the lines larger in order to fit the text and how can i make the nodes squares?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possibility. I defined a new style called `square` that I used instead of `state`. With the `text width` key will wrap automatically, though I added manual line breaks in the example.

The `node distance` key is used to set the default distance between nodes when using `right=of othernode`, so I set that to 3cm.

For the node on the `edge`, I placed that `above` instead of `right`. Another possibility is to remove the `[right]` altogether, and instead add `auto` to the `\draw`, i.e. `\draw [auto] ...`.

You may also be interested in the `quotes` library. This defines a shortcut for making edge nodes. Instead of using `(a) edge node[<options>] {foo} (b)`, you can use `(a) edge["foo"{<options>}] (b)`. (With only one option the braces around `<options>` aren't needed.) I added a second `tikzpicture` in the code below where this is demonstrated.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
   positioning,
   quotes 
}
\begin{document}

% first version, with explicit placement for edge nodes
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  square/.style={
    text width=3cm, % makes the node a minipage-like box of width3cm
    align=center, % center align text in node
    minimum size=3.3cm, % sets minimum width and height
    draw % draw outline
  },
  node distance=3cm % default distance between nodes
]
    % Draw the states
    \node[square]              (aa) {Husband Alive--\\Wife Alive(0)};
    \node[square,right=of aa]  (ad) {Husband Alive--\\Wife Dead(1)};
    \node[square, below=of ad] (dd) {Husband Dead--\\Wife Dead(3)};
    \node[square, below=of aa] (da) {Husband Dead--\\Wife Alive(4)};

    % Connect the states with arrows
    \draw
            (aa) edge node[above] {$m_{x+t:y+t}^{01}$} (ad)
            (ad) edge node[right] {foo} (dd)
            (da) edge node[below] {bar} (dd)
            (aa) edge node[left]  {baz} (da);
\end{tikzpicture}

% second version with automatic placement of edge nodes,
% and the quotes syntax
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  square/.style={
    text width=3cm, % makes the node a minipage-like box of width3cm
    align=center, % center align text in node
    minimum size=3.3cm, % sets minimum width and height
    draw % draw outline
  },
  node distance=3cm, % default distance between nodes
]
    % Draw the states
    \node[square]              (aa) {Husband Alive--\\Wife Alive(0)};
    \node[square, right=of aa] (ad) {Husband Alive--\\Wife Dead(1)};
    \node[square, below=of ad] (dd) {Husband Dead--\\Wife Dead(3)};
    \node[square, below=of aa] (da) {Husband Dead--\\Wife Alive(4)};

    % Connect the states with arrows
    \draw [auto] % automatically places nodes next to path, instead of on top of path
            (aa) edge["$m_{x+t:y+t}^{01}$"] (ad)
            (ad) edge["foo"] (dd)
            (da) edge["bar"swap] (dd)
            (aa) edge["baz"swap] (da);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```